# MySQL STR_TO_DATE returning null

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy to the standard date format yyyy-mm-dd using the STR_TO_DATE function. Some fields in my date column are null and some contain a date.

For instance, 8/22/2011 should become 2011-8-22.

When I select my date column, it looks like this:
8/22/2011
8/10/2010
5/12/2012
etc.

I tried using the code

```
UPDATE table SET date = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

which filled the column with NULL values. Also tried

```
UPDATE table SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

with same result, although this time I did not get a warning message.

Comment: That should work if your column does in deed contain those values. You said you didn't get a warning the second time (`@date` is null as a variable)... What warning did you get the first time?

Comment: In order for this to be a valuable change, you will need to change the column's definition to a datetime -- otherwise you're attempting to insert a DATETIME value into a `VARCHAR` column. (which would work, but it would still be treated as a string and not usable with date functions)

Comment: Hi Michael, in another attempt which I did not post about here, I did indeed attempt to create a new column with a DATE value and insert my values there, but I still got NULL for every value. The warning I received says: 1411 incorrect datetime value: 'NULL' for function str_to_date

Comment: The fact that it says `'NULL'` literally in quotes makes me suspicious of the actual table contents. If it was passing a `NULL`, it would be unquoted. Are you running this within application code or directly in a MySQL client? Can you post a sample of the table rows `SELECT date FROM table LIMIT 10` ?

Comment: I am running in a client, MySQL Workbench. After running the query you suggested, this was my result, which I copied and pasted from the client. ORDER_DATE
8/22/2011
8/10/2010
5/12/2012
1/17/2011
7/17/2015
10/19/2008
9/29/2008
8/4/2010
5/11/2007
12/4/2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is correct:

```
UPDATE table SET date = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

But if the date is not valid (not in %m/%d/%Y format) then it returns NULL

Try executing and then showing warnings. It tells you what is wrong:

```
UPDATE table SET date = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y');
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Maybe some dates are not in format %m/%d/%Y (posibly %d/%m/%Y)

Comment: When I created a dummy date file with only three entries and repeated the process, it worked. something must be wrong with my large date file that is causing the error

Comment: are you getting NULLs in all records? you can check the file and look if there are some wrong values. Also try calling `SHOW WARNINGS` after the UPDATE.

Comment: huh. i just tried the exact same code again and it worked. so weird. anyway thanks for the help.